# How do I need to tag different (but a little similar) entities with Entity-Component-System pattern

Tags: c++, entity-system, entity-component

I have some count of weapons - pistol, shotgun, rifle. And I have one system which deals with all weapons, and another system which deals only with pistol. So I need to create both components "weapons" and "pistol", and I add them both to the entity - "Pistol". So now we have next components - "Weapons", "Pistol", "Rifle", "Shotgun", becase probably I will need to have separate system for different weapons in future. 
Then in the same reasons I create next Components - "Character", "Player", "Enemy", "Friend" (maybe more types of Enemies and Friends), "Ammo", "AmmoForPistol", "AmmoForRifle" ... 
And there are too much different components only for tagging different entities regarding to the types. 
How can I avoid this amount of Components?

Comment: Why not have the weapon component specify what type of weapon it is and what / how much ammo it has?

Comment: And then system which need to deal only with an entity - "Pistol" (or Shotgun ...), will have to work with all weapons-entity instead only one entity- "Pistol". Under "will have to work" I mean that an update cycle will have to go through all weapons on the level to find "Pistol".

Comment: What does the system that is specific to the pistol need to do different? i.e. what makes a system handling the general weapon component incapable of what is specific to a 'pistol entity'? As for your Character, Player etc component, you need to wonder whether these should be components itself in the first place, or whether the entities aren't simply a composite of already existing components (e.g. a player has a collider and  an enemy too, so they are handled by the same system). Try to find the parts entities will have in common

Comment: @Athosvk Pistol it is for example)) There will be something like grenade launcher. ) But thanks I understand your thought? so try to find out solution.

Comment: Something tells me that the foundations of your ECS design is a bit shaky. Characters, Players, Enemy, Friends, etc seem to me as they should be _entities_, not _components_. Same goes for Weapons and Pistols.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt yes, I know that) But also I can use "empty components-classes" for tagging different entity. For example if entity has "Weapons_component" it means that this entity is some weapons etc.

Comment: Oh, empty component classes as tags! That's interesting!

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Do you think is bad idea?

Comment: I don't know :) You try it and tell us the results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no harm in adding a single `WeaponComponent` which holds a `TYPE` attribute to describe whether it's a Pistol, Rifle, Shotgun, Knife, etc.

Nothing dictates however that you must store all `WeaponComponent` instances in the same list inside your `WeaponSystem` either.  In fact, to avoid branching on specific use cases, it might be advantageous to store each  `WeaponComponent` in a type-specific list and simply iterate over multiple lists as part of your update loop.

I also don't believe that *Character* and *Player* make sense to be represented as components.

In order to determine hostility vs friendly could simply be derived by checking whether the entity in question has a specific type of component, perhaps `HostileComponent`.  The assumption here being that all entities are friendly unless that component exists.

There are plenty of ways to split / tag things through components without going overboard.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid this amount of Components?

You can't.

ECS are made to decouple and *specialize* your game logic. You'll want your components to represent something specific. By doing so, you won't have a choice: you have many tiny components.

Comment: A component is meant to represent a cohesive junction of data for a specific feature.  That doesn't imply that a component represents something so specific that you end up with hundreds or thousands of tiny components.  As my answer points out, you have lots of choices with how you interact with components.  A single component can represent multiple ideas that are shared and it becomes the responsibility of your systems to take advantage of programming paradigms to use those components efficiently and effectively without overburdening the user of such ECS frameworks.

Comment: @Naros _"[...] you have lots of choices with how you interact with components."_ There you go. It really depends on how you view your ECS, how you've built it. The main reason I see of using an ECS architecture is to not overburden components with what you don't need, keep them as lean as possible in order to maximize what you get from it. I guess making a good software with ECS is an art, though.

Comment: @Naros I don't disagree with your answer, though :)